# Writing MapInfo Label Expression to label lots in format Map-Lot (017-001) with just Lot

Tags: mapinfo, labeling

I am trying to label map lots in this format Map-Lot (017-001) and I was wondering if there was a label expression that would allow me to only show the lot number and not the map number.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly, you might have values in the **Map-Lot** field that look like the following:

```
017-001
017-002
018-121
```

And you only want to show the portion after the "-".  So, the above would be displayed like this:

```
001
002
121
```

If your Lot number is always going to be three characters long, then you can use the following label expression:

**`Right$(Map-Lot,3)`**

However, if your field values are like this:

```
017-001
018-1234
017-184855
```

Then you can use something like the following:

**`Mid$(Map-Lot, InStr(1, Map-Lot, "-")+1, Len(Map-Lot))`**

Your resulting labels will look like the following:

```
001
1234
184855
```

You can have a look in the MapInfo documentation on string functions for more explanation of the **Mid$**, **Right$**, and **InStr** functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try Mid$(Map-Lot, 5, 3) if all of the Map-Lot are the same number of digits.